# how to initialize an array list of type Person

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created a container List which holds an array of type Person[]    . The class SimplepersonDatabase performs add, remove, find, and delete persons. I understand my question might be off topic, but I have spent more than a week on this and I seem not to be getting anywhere.

my question is **how can I initialize the container I have just created?** I want to be able to perform the functions implemented in SimplePersonDataBase. Thanks for your time. I am really really stuck. Other implement such as an array of type int and type String is very understandable, but I cannot apply the knowledge in creating this

Thanks

```
 class List {  // seperate List.java class
            int size;
            Person[] person;
            int next;

        public List(){
            this.size=100;
            this.person = new Person[size];
            this.next=0;
        }
        }

    public class Person {   // Seperate Person.java class
        public String fn;
        public String ln;
        public Date dob;
        public int id;
    }


    public class SimplePersonDataBase {//Seperate SimplePersonDataBase.java class

        public static void go(){

    Person person[] = new Person[4];
    String[] firstname = { "denis", "cyprian", "ben", "albert" };
    String[] lastname = { "Ayuk", "Bisong", "Agbor", "Arrey" };
    int[] id = {120, 154, 547, 563 };


    for (int i = 0; i < firstname.length; i++) {
        person[i] = new Person();
        person[i].fn= firstname[i];
        person[i].ln= lastname[i];
        person[i].dob= new Date();



    }

    person[3] = new Person();
    person[3].fn= firstname[1];
    person[3].ln= lastname[1];
    person[3].dob= new Date();
    person[3].dob= DateFunctions.makeDate(1990, 10, 17);
        }

        public static boolean add(Person[] person, Person personadd){

        }

        /*
         * This function sorts an array of persons. The sort-criterion is specified by the int
    argument and is analogous to the meaning of the int argument in
    int compareTo(Person, Person, int)
         */
        public static void sort(Person[] a, int opt){

            for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++){

                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    Person temp = new Person();
                    if(PersonFunctions.compareTo(a[j-1], a[j],opt)> 0){
                        temp = a[j];
                        a[j] = a[j+1];
                        a[j + 1] = temp;

                    }

                }


            }
        }


        public static void swap(Person[] person, int i, int j){

            Person tmp = new Person();
            if ((j>=0 && j<person.length) && (i>=0 && i<person.length))
            tmp = person[j];
            person[j] = person[i];
            person[i] = tmp;

        }

        public static int find(Person[] a, String b){

            int keyIndex = -1;

            for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++){
                if(a[i].ln==b){
                    keyIndex = i;
                }
            }
            return keyIndex;

        }

        /*
         * Removes the Person with index idx from the list. and returns the removed Person,
    or null if idx is out of range.
    This function is tricky, because It is not allowed to leave a gap in the array. That
    means you have to shift all elements after the removed one.
         */
        public static Person remove (Person[] person, int idx){

            Person removed = new Person();

            if(idx<0 || idx>=person.length){
                removed = null;
            }
            if(person[idx]==null){
                removed=null;
                }

            for (int i = 0; i<person.length; i++){
                if(i==idx){
                    removed = person[i];
                }
            }

            for (int k=idx; k<person.length; k++){
                person[k] = person[k+1];
            }

            return removed;

        }

        public static void display(Person[] p) {
            for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
                if (p[i] == null)
                    System.out.printf(null);
                else
                    TextIO.putf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", i, p[i].id, p[i].fn, p[i].ln, p[i].dob);

            TextIO.putln();

    }
    //  public static void display(Person[] p, int personFormat, int dateFormat){
    //      display(p);
    //      switch(personFormat){
    //          case 1: PersonFunctions.display(p, 1); break;
    //          case 2: PersonFunctions.display(p,2); break;
    //      default: display(p);break;
    //      }
    //  }


        public static void main(String[] args) {


            go();

        }

            TextIO.put("Welcome to the SimplePersonDatabase.\n");
            TextIO.putln();

            int option;
            do{

                TextIO.put("available options:\n1) list\n2) add\n3) remove\n4) sort\n5) find\n6) settings\n0) quit\nyour choice:");
                option = TextIO.getInt();

                switch(option){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    TextIO.putln("sort by:\n1) Firstname\n2) Birth\nall other values: lastname");
                    switch(TextIO.getInt()){
                    case 1:
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    default :
                        break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;
                case 0:
                    TextIO.put("Thank you for using the SimplePersonDatabase.");
                    break;
                case 99:
                    break;
                default :
                    TextIO.put("illegal option.");
                    break;
                }

            }while(option !=0);

    }
```

Comment: Person[] pers=new Person[]{}; ?

Comment: You are already initializing the person array in the List() constructor.  We don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to know how to reference List and pass in Person[] as parameter into my functions. Person[] hold list if persons. The implementation is not getting to me. My functions have to accept parameter of type Person[] in the SimplePersonDatabase.

Comment: Your main method doesn't seem right either (the "{" after go).. but you try to call `go();` without actually having an instance of `SimplePersonDataBase`

Comment: Right Kuba, I commented it because my implementation were totally off the link. Your suggestions and assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: No that's fine, the code is probably irrelevant. But in your `main()` you call `go()` which is not a static method, there should be some `SimplePersonDataBase spDB = new SimplePersonDataBase();` and then `spDB.go();`

Comment: I have updated the go to what I formally have to give you a clear idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unlikely to be needed, but maybe you meant how to deal with Person constructors.
- Made the List complete (add, remove, numberOfPersons) and without redundancy (size, next).
- In SimplePersonDataBasse one should use `List`, not `Person[]` especially as only part of the array is filled.

Rests to say there are java collection classes like [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), ArrayList and others, that offer built-in functionality for dynamic lists instead of fixed-size arrays.

```
class List {

    Person[] persons;
    int count;

    public List() {
        this(100);
    }

    public List(int initialCapacity) {
        persons = new Person[initialCapacity];
    }

    public int numberOfPersons() {
        return count;
    }

    public void add(Person person) {
        checkUniqueId(person);
        if (count >= persons.length) {
            // Enlarge array
            persons = Arrays.copyOf(persons, persons.length + 100);
        }
        persons[count] = person;
        ++count;
    }

    private void checkUniqueId(Person person) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            if (persons[i].id == person.id) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already a person with id "
                    + person.id);
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove(int personId) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            if (persons[i].id == personId) {
                --count;
                persons[i] = persons[count];
                persons[count] = null;
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No person known with id "
            + personId);
    }
}

public class Person {

    public String fn;
    public String ln;
    public Date dob;
    public int id; // Must be unique

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String fn, String ln, Date dob, int id) {
        this.fn = fn;
        this.ln = ln;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class SimplePersonDataBase {

    private List list;
    private int nextPersonId;

    public boolean add(Person personadd) {
        personadd.id = nextPersonId;
        ++nextPersonId;
        list.add(personadd);
    }
}
```